# htaccess - redirect to php file with GET

Tags: php, file, .htaccess, get

Some user will access a content of my site with this URL: www.example.com/example

But I need to be redirected to: www.example.com/page.php?p=example

So all values ​​that I put after the slash is redirected to the page.php, as the value of "p" parameter.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea and one that's been implemented many times before. Did you have a question?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about clicking the duplicates you got when typing in the title of your question.

Comment: I could not explain exactly the problem, my english is not good, but by coincidence I found what I needed at: http://corz.org/server/tricks/htaccess2.php

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This question is quite easy and has been asked before.
This is why I will not give you the exact answer, but rather redirect you to tutorials and guidelines explaining you what to do. This'll allow you to understand the solution even better.

If you're running your site on an Apache server, you can use Mod Rewrite.
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Also check this out:
http://corz.org/server/tricks/htaccess2.php

But as people seem to downvote me because of this, I'll help you out.
In your .htaccess file, you place the following

Whenever you use mod_rewrite (the part of Apache that does all this magic), you need to do before any ReWrite rules. You only need to do this once per .htaccess file.
*+FollowSymLinks* must be enabled for any rules to work, this is a security requirement of the rewrite engine. Normally it's enabled in the root and you shouldn't have to add it, but it doesn't hurt to do so

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*) page.php?p=$1 [NC]
```

*NC* means *no-case* a.k.a. *case-insensitive*.
You can also add *L* (-> *[NC,L]*) to inidicate this is the Last Rewrite Rule.

You may have noticed, the solution above uses regular expression to match variables. What that simply means is.. match the part inside (.+) and use it to construct "$1" in the new URL. In other words, (.+) = $1 you could have multiple (.+) parts and for each, mod_rewrite automatically creates a matching $1, $2, $3, etc, in your target (aka. 'substitution') URL.

Comment: Why did anyone -1 this? Although his question is offtopic, I still like to redirect the OP to a solution

Comment: Because it is a very vague almost link only answer. And if you want to help OP you can find a suitable dupe.

Comment: I rather give him the Apache website explaining Mod_rewrite, than give him the literal solution to this easy question

Comment: *sigh* thanks for reminding me to not comment of downvotes. It never ends well...